# Getting data out of MatchData got as a result from match function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have an array of custom objects in it. Those objects have a parameter called name which is a concatenation of 2 strings having a delimiter in between. Eg: name could be Some@Data where 'Some' is first string and 'Data' is another and @ is a delimiter.

My intention is update the name parameter for all the objects inside the array such that the param would only have 'Data' (i.e. remove 'Some@') and store the objects inside another array after updating. Below is the code:

```
final_array = array1.select do |object|
   object.name = object.name.match(/@(.*?)$/)
end
```

When I print `object.name.match(/@(.*?)$/)` this gives me output as:

```
#<MatchData "@Data" 1:"Data">
```

Out of this output, how do I get "Data" from this MatchData. I tried `object.name.match(/@(.*?)$/)[1]` but it didn't work. Or do I need to change my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use #each and #gsub methods:

```
array.each do |object|
  object.name = object.name.gsub(/^.+@/, '')
end
```

Comment: Hmmm gsub works great! I got the required output. Still wondering whats wrong with match. I mean when I refer ruby docs it says output[0] should give me the value - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html But I get an error.

Comment: This works for me:
    irb(main):001:0> "Some@Data".match(/@(.*?)$/)[1]
    => "Data"

Comment: Hmmm strange. Wonder if something is wrong with the way am saving it inside a variable.

Comment: But THANKS for trying in irb for me!! Atleast I got to know it works and can debug deeper into the way am storing it.